# List using xlrd; find string in list

Tags: python, list, xlrd

Got a questions about finding a string in a list using Python.
First I open my Excel-file using xlrd, and make a list of one column. This column are all the communities I want to use.
Next I have another file with communities and I only want to use those communities that are present in the excel-file I opened before. Shortly, I do a piece with the following code:

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\Users\Yannick\Desktop\MASTERPROEF\Bestanden_LAMBIT\Excel_Files\From_A\ANTWERP_CORRECT.xls")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
gemeente = 'CELLES'
rl = sh.col_values(4,start_rowx=1)
print rl
if gemeente in rl:
    print "OK"
```

But it gives a problem. It prints 'OK', what means that 'CELLES' is linked with  a community called 'COURCELLES' in the list (I know because 'CELLES' is not in the list. Thus when python searches the list for 'CELLES', it gives a positive match with 'COURCELLES'. Does anyone has an idea how to search for 100 % identical matches? So that 'CELLES' never get linked with 'COURCELLES', just because *a part of the string* is identical?

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` instead of `in` in your comparison:

```
if gemeente == rl:
```

[in](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) operator is a membership test and returns:

> True if an item of s is equal to x, else False

While `==` compares the values of two (in your case `str`) objects. More info on [comparisons](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/reference/expressions.html#notin).

Comment: I tried doing that, but when I search for one that is definitely in the list it gives nothing. So when searching through the list using that line, no matches are being found. :-/

Comment: @user8608 Try removing whitespace from your `rl` values with [strip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip)

Comment: It still does not work using strip.
'COURCELLES' is in the list, 'CELLES' is NOT in the list.
And still Python says 'CELLES' is in the list, because it is a part of 'COURCELLES'.
By using == instead of 'in', no records were returned. But even the right matches does not exist. :s

Comment: @user8608 Please update your answer with some sample data formatted as CSV